# PHP vs Python For Web Crawler

Tags: php, python, web-crawler

i am planning to make web crawler which can crawl 200+ domain, which of the language will be suitable for it. I am quite familiar with PHP but an amateur at Python.

Comment: both of these languages are really slow. I would use C, C++, C#, Java or Julia for anything requiring performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built crawlers in both languages. While I personally find it easy to make a crawler in python because of huge number of freely available libraries for html parsing, I would recommend that you go with the language you are most comfortable with. Build a well designed and efficient crawler in a language you know well and you will get even better at that language. There is no feature which can not be implemented in either of the two languages so just make a decision and start working.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try both. Make one in php and one in python. It'll help you learn the language even if you're experienced. Never say no to opportunities to practice.